# snowflake-csv fileformat to read only 2 line and rest of the data

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

I have a requirement to create an external table from a csv file data. But, in every file at Row 3 - we will receive a date value, which we need to create as a new column along with the column data from the csv. Wanted to understand how to populate the date value into a new column or we can create different external table on top of first three rows and use it??

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE TEST_CSV_TABLE1(
  period VARCHAR AS (value:c1::varchar),
  Good name VARCHAR AS (value:c2::varchar)
  Customer Name VARCHAR AS (value:c2::varchar)
)
WITH LOCATION = @TEST_STAGE
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = CSV FIELD_DELIMITER = ',');
```

The csv data looks below:

[image]

Comment: You can create an external table over the actual csv data in your file I.e. starting at row 5 (by using the SKIP_HEADER parameter in the file format) . You can’t do the rest of of what you are asking with external tables - not unless you edit the files first

Comment: A fundamental response to your question - rather than try to load an Excel report into Snowflake, it would likely be better to get the data that generates the report into Snowflake and then create the report from Snowflake.

Comment: Snowflake file formats will not handle this use case. If you are unable to get the file reformatted, or get access to the source data as Mike Walton suggests, you will need to write a stored procedure to read the file, reformat, and load into the table.